# How does Css Media Queries and Javascript Orientation Works?

Tags: javascript, css

I am little bit confused, and eager to understand how does the media queries and javascript orientation events works. and I have couple of questions like:

1. For example I have css `media queries` in place and also at the same time on page load am triggering javascript orientation event using `match media`.

As far it is concern css will load first and then js.

1. But while dealing with orientations change from portrait to landscape or vice versa in a real device, which will have the higher preference css or js?
2. which will get impacted first on dom js or css?

Comment: If the javascript is applying the CSS to the element, then it will override all external CSS (that isn't marked with an `!important` tag)

Comment: @Jonathan Brooks, My point to understand is which will have the higher preference while changing the orientaitons, js or css